# Django Form Validation Framework on AppEngine: How to strip out HTML etc.?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm using the Django Form Validation Framework on AppEngine (http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/djangoforms.html), like this:

```
data = MyForm(data=self.request.POST)
  if data.is_valid():
    entity = data.save(commit=False)
    entity.put()
```

I wonder if there's a way to preprocess the POST data (strip out malicious code, HTML etc.) before storing it. It seems that any form validation library should offer something like that, no?

Thanks

Hannes

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

`forms.is_valid()` auto populates a dictionary `forms.cleaned_data` by calling a method called clean(). If you want to do any custom validation define your own 'clean_filed_name' that returns the cleaned field value or raises `forms.ValidationError()`. On error, the corresponding error on the field is auto populated.

Long answer:

[Refer Documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers above, a different perspective: Don't. Store the user input with as little processing as is practical, and sanitize the data on output. Django templates provide filters for this - 'escape' is one that escapes all HTML tags.

The advantage of this approach over sanitizing the data at input time is twofold: You can change how you sanitize data at any time without having to 'grandfather in' all your old data, and when a user wants to edit something, you can show them the original data they entered, rather than the 'cleaned up' version. Cleaning up data at the wrong time is also a major cause of things like double-escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. Have you tried reading the forms documentation?

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/